# Convert this statement to sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

Display the package number and the number of customers for each package number, only for packages with more than 100 customers.

```
SELECT pack_num, COUNT(customer) 
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY pack_num
HAVING COUNT(customer) >100
```

Is this query right? If not please correct me.

Comment: yes, right..... by the way, please use Ctrl+K for formatting your queries for your future question.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't to be used to get other people to confirm if small snippets of code are correct. You should test them yourself! It's a useful skill that is much faster than asking here.

Comment: Oh okay will do this is my first time asking a question here :p

Comment: Your query is fine. You should only use `count(distinct)` if it is appropriate for the question, because `count(distinct)` is generally more expensive than just `count()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To count only the unique costumers you could add a [DISTINCT to the COUNT](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-count-with-distinct.php).

```
SELECT pack_num, COUNT(DISTINCT customer) 
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY pack_num
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT customer) >100
```